# Get Camera IP Address

Tags: c#, exception, camera, ip

I'm finding a way to retrieve all the IP addresses of the IP cameras that connect to my computer through Ethernet switches in the Net 5.0 project.

I did try to use the OzekiSDK library that targets Net Framework to solve this problem:

```
    void GetIpCameras()
    {
        IPCameraFactory.DeviceDiscovered += IPCameraFactory_DeviceDiscovered;
        IPCameraFactory.DiscoverDevices();
    }

    private void IPCameraFactory_DeviceDiscovered(object sender, DiscoveryEventArgs e)
    {
        GuiThread(() => DiscoveredDeviceList.Items.Add("Host: " + e.Device.Host + " Port: " + e.Device.Port));
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DiscoveredDeviceList.Items.Clear();
        IPCameraFactory.DeviceDiscovered -= IPCameraFactory_DeviceDiscovered;

        GetIpCameras();
    }
```

result:    Host: 192.168.0.148 Port: 80

The upper method work perfectly, but only if my project was target Net FrameWork, currently I'm building a project that targets Net 5.0 with many libraries that only target Net, so if I try to use this library, it will return an exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Ozeki.Camera.IPCameraFactory' threw an exception.'
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Discovery, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

after that, I thought it would be a good idea to put this code in a new net Framework project and then use it as a reference for my current Net 5.0 project, and turns out the result still the same.
I'm hoping to find a solution for this.

Comment: According the documentation of the Namespace, it is not compatible with .NET 5. So you can't use it there. Have in mind, that .Net Framework and .Net5 are not compatible

Comment: @TheTanic is there any way I can achieve the same result without using OzekiSDK .Net Framework Library? This Library is mainly used for Computer Vision

Comment: Do the cameras have a UDP broadcast to identify themselves on the network? If not, then the library probably checks for (a) specific port(s) being open for every possible IP address in your subnet.

Comment: In there Datasheet, they only mention .NET Framework. So I would say no. But maybe you should contact them. They should be able to help you

Comment: Vendors of cameras does not seem to be on the leading edge of supporting newer versions of .Net. But they are more likely to update if they get requests to do so.

Comment: @LIama Do you know if there are any Libraries similar to this or somehow check port as you mention?